# discord.ui import failure - Python 3 and Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

I've tried to import discord.ui and discord in python.
I've installed it via `python3 -m pip install discord.ui` and imported it via `from discord.ui import View, Button`. Discord.py: `python3 -m pip install discord.py` - Imported via `import discord`

If I try to start the program, the following errors came up.

[failure messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63ZBa.png)

I'm using PyCharm and I can't figure out what's the error..

Importing discord, discord.ui, discord.ext, asyncio

--> no error messages and full functionability

Comment: Did you install any other discord-related packages or forks? These tend to break dpy installations. Either way, uninstall everything discord-related, and then force-reinstall dpy.

Comment: No, I don't have anything installed what could be discord relevant. I've only installed `discord-py discord-ui dotenv`

Comment: There you go, discord-ui is already something that is discord relevant. `discord.ui` is built into the `discord.py` lib. "`discord.ui`" doesn't exist on pypi so I don't think that that `pip install` was very useful. Either way, `discord.py` is all you need... `.ui` is just a module inside of it

Comment: Yeah, but I tried both.. Only the install of `discord.py` resulted at the same error either.